Ошибка "Ссылка на неразрешенную лексему" при подключении стороннего проекта с необходимыми методами. c++
Есть заголовочный файл, содержащий определение для класса
//
#pragma once

#include <string>

extern "C" {
#include <openssl/types.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509_vfy.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/pem2.h>
}

class CertificateOperator
{
private:

// поля класса

public:

CertificateOperator(const std::string& cert_file, const std::string& key_file);

void read_certificate(X509* cert);

void read_certificate();

void createSelfSignedCert();

// ...

};

//
Заголовочный файл подключается и используется в другом проекте:
 #include "../Certification_center_console/CertificateOperator.h".

Как итог, в проекте, к которому подключается данный файл, возникают следующие ошибки:
"неразрешенный внешний символ "extern "C" void __cdecl X509_free(struct x509_st *)" (?X509_free@@$$J0YAXPAUx509_st@@@Z). "

"ссылка на неразрешенную лексему (0A00046B) "public: __thiscall CertificateOperator::CertificateOperator(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0CertificateOperator@@$$FQAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allo cator@D@2@@std@@0@Z) в функции "private: void __clrcall KFF::TestForm::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@TestForm@KFF@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)"

"ссылка на неразрешенную лексему (0A00046C) "public: void __thiscall CertificateOperator::createSelfSignedCert(void)" (?createSelfSignedCert@CertificateOperator@@$$FQAEXXZ) в функции "private: void __clrcall KFF::TestForm::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@TestForm@KFF@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)"

и так далее для каждого метода подключаемого класса
При использовании класса в этом же проекте ошибок не наблюдается

Другой проект точно компилируется C++ (а не Си) компилятором? В любом случае я бы заключил все С++-ные части в #ifdef __cplusplus "скобки"

"В первом проекте, наверное есть файл CertificateOperator.cpp и библиотека openssl. А в другом проекте только заголовочный файл." - все именно так и есть. Разве я не могу просто использовать методы из другого проекта, или необходимо все писать в одном? (но ведь это не совсем корректно)
